# Custom UIView in UITableView cells with UITableViewAutomaticDimension enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension, intrinsic-content-size

I have `UITableView` with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and some `estimatedRowHeight`. For this table I am using custom `UITableViewCell` which contains some label and custom `UIView` with overridden `intrinsicContentSize()`. Constraints setup is correct and table is able to determine actual height for each row. So far so good.

Now I started to modify internal logic of my custom view to adapt it's appearance based on available width i.e. when table cell size is not wide enough my view can rearrange subviews to fit new limitation and this have impact to resulting height, so I have code like that:

```
var internalSize: CGSize = ...

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return internalSize
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    fitIntoWidth(frame.size.width)
}

private func fitIntoWidth(width: CGFloat) {
    let height = // calculate based on content and width
    internalSize = CGSizeMake(width, height)
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

Now, when I populate table view, `intrinsicContentSize()` returns some desired value but it is not good fit for current layout, then control goes to `layoutSubviews()` where size get recalculated and system again calls `intrinsicContentSize()` and now it returns good value. However, first time table loads data and cell heights calculated based on incorrect `intrinsicContentSize()` values. If I call `reloadData()` again all becomes fine and layout is also ok for all upcoming cells in table.

Where is my mistake and how to modify code to make cell sizing work correctly without calling `reloadData()` twice?

Comment: why are you overriding the intrinsic size?

Comment: @BangOperator because default implementation doesn't provide any information about view's size and in that case you should explicitly set height constraint to view. But I want some implementation like in `UILabel` - you just set it's text and never height - label itself calculates desired size

Comment: how about [cell layoutIfNeeded]; just before returning cell in cellForRow.. method

Comment: @Alok nothing changes. I think that I should change something inside the custom view itself, because cells only with labels work fine without any additional calls to layout outside

Comment: so basically with the override intrinsic size you are calculating UIView size ? can not it be done through systemLayoutSizeFittingSize or with CGRectGetMaxY and CGRectGetMaxX

Comment: @Alok `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` not get called at all. And [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html) also mentions intrinsic content size

Comment: can you also show code for heightForRowMethod ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113038/discussion-between-azat-and-alok).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @Eduard just manual calculations using all delegate methods to report exact values, without automatic row height mode